# How to turn off Steam privacy settings

Tags: steam, gog

GOG Connect warns to "Make sure your Steam Privacy Settings & Profile Status are set to public" but doesn't specify how. I don't see an option for this in the Steam desktop app's settings. What do I need to change to set this info as public?

Comment: You mean Steam mobile app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### https://steamcommunity.com/my/edit/settings

[This page](https://steamcommunity.com/my/edit/settings) contains both the "Profile Status" and inventory privacy ("Steam Privacy Settings").

[image: SETTINGS]

(As a reminder, you can return to private settings once GOG Connect has done its thing.)

Comment: [One link that works with all accounts (provided you're logged in), no substitution of anything required.](http://steamcommunity.com/my/edit/settings)

Comment: I think by "Steam app" author meant Steam Windows/Linux/Mac client or mobile app. steam://url/SteamIDEditPage opens [this](https://steamcommunity.com/my/edit) page in client (couldn't find any better url). For mobile app, it's in Settings > Application Settings > Steam Settings > Privacy Settings.